# how do I stop this loop? I tried even if statement to stop it

Tags: java, while-loop

```
//c is an integer passed to count how many times the while looped before stopping
public static int ask(String[] p, String[] n, int c)
{

    int i = 0;

    while(p[i] != "stop")
    {
        p[i] = input("postcode ? ");
        n[i] = input("name ?");
        if(p[i].equals("stop"))
        {
            break;
        }

        i++;
        c++;
    }

    return c;
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see  if `p[i] == "stop"` ?

Comment: I tried it didn't work

Comment: this is java code

Answer (score 0):

while loop will not stop unless it is false.

```
int i = 0;

    while(p[i] != "stop")
```

from this code you can see that if `p[i] is ! = "stop"` it will do the following action until `p[i] == "stop"`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need this code if your while loop is working correctly.

```
if(p[i].equals("stop"))
    {
        break;
    }
```

Your while loop should check if:

```
p[i] != "stop"
```

and if the above statement is true it will execute the loop. If this is not working and your loop continues indefinitely then p[i] always equals "stop". Also the top part of your code is not formatted correctly in the question so I'm not entirely sure what it does but the static keyword may be preventing values you are expecting to change from changing.

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys I fixed it.

```
   int i = 0;
    p[i]="";
    while(!p[i].equals("stop"))
    {
       i++;
        p[i] = input("postcode ? ");
        n[i] = input("name ?");

        c++;
    }
```